# How do i take the random number from a slot machine and use it to accordingly to calculate the wins and losses in C++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, random

I need to generate 3 random numbers between 2 and 7 and that part is okay. Now my if else statements are not working because I don't know how to use that random value to calculate the winnings. Also for some reason, my else statement which is supposed to be "you lost" is not working because I missed {} when I did not, its right there. And also, I need the program to automatically keep on going in the slot machine until you lose the game and that is not working either.

**Full Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int options = 0;

    std::cout << "Your Balance: 2000$" << endl;
    int bet = 2000;

    std::cout << endl;
    string op1 = "Press 1: Play slots ";
    std::cout << op1 << endl;

    string op2 = "Press 2: Check Credits";
    std::cout << op2 << endl;

    string op3 = "Press 3: End Game";
    std::cout << op3 << endl;

    std::cout << endl;
    std::cin >> options;
    std::cout << endl;

    bool YN = true;

    if (options == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Let's Play!";
        std::cout << endl;
        std::cout << "Enter Bet:  ";
        std::cin >> bet;

        while (bet <= 2000)
        {
            std::cout << endl;

            int game_num = 0;
            std::random_device real_random;
            std::mt19937 gen(real_random());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(2, 7);

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            std::cout << distrib(gen);
            
            if (777)
            {
                bet = bet * 10;
                std::cout << "You Won: " << bet << endl;
                return 0;
            }
            else if (222 || 333 || 444 || 555 || 666)
            {
                bet = bet * 5;
                std::cout << "You Won: " << bet << endl;    
                return 0;
            }
            else if (223 || 224 || 225 || 226 || 227 || 332 || 334 || 335 || 336 || 337 || 442 || 443 || 445 || 446 || 447 || 552 || 553 || 554 || 556 || 557 || 662 || 663 || 664 || 665 || 667);
            {
                bet = bet * 3;
                std::cout << "You Won: " << bet << endl;
                return 0;
            }
// This is the else statement that is not working 
            else
            {
                std::cout << "You lost" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (options == 2)
    {
        std::cout << bet;
    }
    else if (options == 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Game Over";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "!!Please enter a valid option!!";
    }
    int Y_N;
    cout << "Would you like to continue? 1 = Yes, 2 = No" << endl;
    cin >> Y_N;

    if (Y_N == 2)
    YN = false;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (777)` -- `else if (222 || 333 || 444 || 555 || 666)` -- Does the C++ book that you are using show any `if` statements that looks like that?  Explain what you are trying to accomplish on those lines of code, because whatever it is you're trying to accomplish, those lines of code will not do it.

Comment: `if (777)` is always true. Usually you'd want to store your result in a variable and compare that against a value. Like `int result = getResult(); if (result == 777) { ... }`

Comment: Store `distrib(gen)` into a variable use that in the `if` statements like `auto value=distrib(gen); if(value==777 || value==222)`...

Comment: @OP -- Take this as advice -- What I don't understand is how you are able to put together the code to generate random numbers (something most beginners cannot do), but at the same time, not able to form a correct `if` statement that every beginner knows to do.  Are you using good C++ books to learn from, or are you simply copying code without actually learning C++ properly?

Comment: So basically, you enter a bet under 2000 to proceed then I will generate 3 random numbers between 2 and 7 for each number and if your result is 777 then your bet gets multiplied by 10, if all 3 numbers are same except 777 like for example 555, 666 then your bet gets multiplied by 5, if its 2 out of 3 numbers that are same, for example 223 or 454 then your bet gets multiplied by 3. Else you lose the game. Then if you have won, whatever the bet you entered in gets multiplied by what you won, displays your total which is 2000 + what you won, and then asks if you would like to continue.

Comment: Do yourself and your rando-generator a favor and move `std::random_device real_random; std::mt19937 gen(real_random());` to the *top* of `main`. In fact, further consolidate them and just `std::mt19937 gen{ std::random_device{}() };` instead, whilst doing so.

Comment: @VishalV *if your result is 777* -- You failed to do this.  You just have `777` in the `if` statement.  How is the `if` supposed to know that the 777 is supposed to be associated to the call to get the random number?  `int x = 777; int y = 888; if (777)...` -- does the `if` statement know to use `x` instead of `y`?  Of course it doesn't.  As already mentioned:  `result = getResult();` and then you use `result` in the `if` statement.

Comment: Suggest using a switch statement here.

Comment: @VishalV Did the comments or my answer solve your issue? If the answer helped, you can say thanks by up voting and/or checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You must save you results. I picked a variable called `r` here. So change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
std::cout << distrib(gen);
```

To:

```
int r = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    r = 10 * r + distrib(gen);
}
std::cout << r << endl;
```

Change your 777 check to:

```
if (r == 777)
```

Also changed the triples check to:

```
else if (r==222 || r== 333 || r== 444 || r== 555 || r==666)
```

Finally changed the rest:

```
else if (r==223 || r==224 || r==225 || r==226 || r==227 || r==332 || r==334 || r==335 || r==336 || r==337 || r==442 || r==443 || r==445 || r==446 || r==447 || r==552 || r==553 || r==554 || r==556 || r==557 || r==662 || r==663 || r==664 || r==665 || r==667)
```